# Azure Disk Encryption Linux VM key rotation

Tags: linux, azure, encryption, azure-keyvault

So, lets say I've encrypted Linux VM on Azure (boy, the docs are awful). How do I rotate the keys? Is it even possible? Right now I see that Azure offers passphrase encryption. I suppose you can't really "rotate" that?

But let's imagine I've used KEK (key encryption keys) to encrypt passphrase which is used to encrypt Linux VM, I don't think there's a way to rotate that except for remove encryption\enable encryption?

Am I missing something?

vm encoded with Passphrase which is in turn encrypted with kek

Comment: How did you go about encrypting the VM?

Comment: hey did you get the answer I am searching the same? is key rotation of kek is possible in azure ?

Comment: no clue yet, i don't think there's a way for this @sonam_sharma

Comment: yes even I am not able to find any documentation regarding that.

Comment: we can rotate the secrets and storage keys ? right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote:

> To rotate secrets, just call the same command you used originally to
>   enable disk encryption, specifying a different Key Vault. To rotate
>   the key encryption key, call the same command you used originally to
>   enable disk encryption, specifying the new key encryption.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security/azure-security-disk-encryption-faq#how-do-i-rotate-secrets-or-encryption-keys